# touchesBegan and touchesMoved stuck

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am using this code in my app to recognize touch and drag on specific `UIView`,

now i have a problem that if i make the touch and immediate make a drag the `touchesMoved` called only 3-4 times and stop and then the `touchesCancelled` called, but if i touch the screen wait a second and then make a drag it call `touchesMoved` every time the finger move.

## Edit

Ijust tested it on iphone 4s and with this device it work perfect,in ipod4 it still have the problem. both device are with 5.01 .

```
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
            NSArray* touchArray = [touches allObjects];

        UITouch* touch = [touchArray objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        UIView *tmp = [self.view hitTest:point withEvent:event];

        if (tmp == volumeViewBackground) {
            //do something
        }else {
            NSLog(@"err");
        }

     }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSArray* touchArray = [touches allObjects];

    UITouch* touch = [touchArray objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *tmp = [self.view hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (tmp == volumeViewBackground) {
        //do something
    }else {
        NSLog(@"err");
    }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{ 
    NSLog(@"error");
}
```

Comment: There is not enough code here to show what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `super` according to UIResponder [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];

        NSArray* touchArray = [touches allObjects];

        UITouch* touch = [touchArray objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        UIView *tmp = [self.view hitTest:point withEvent:event];

        if (tmp == volumeViewBackground) {
            //do something
        }else {
            NSLog(@"err");
        }

     }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];

    NSArray* touchArray = [touches allObjects];

    UITouch* touch = [touchArray objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *tmp = [self.view hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (tmp == volumeViewBackground) {
        //do something
    }else {
        NSLog(@"err");
    }
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{ 

   [super touchesCancelled: touches withEvent: event]; 

   NSLog(@"error");
}
```